# How bitcoins increase their value

Tags: bitcoin-economy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How is the exchange rate for Bitcoin established?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/2566/how-is-the-exchange-rate-for-bitcoin-established)

I notice that bitcoins are sold on the market with alternate prices.

How is their price established ?

Who is establishing how much a coin worths ?

Thanks

Comment: Hi opC0de! This question has been asked and answered before. See the link attached to your post.

Answer (score 1):

There is no central pricing body. The [open market](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_market) is determining the price. What customers of the exchanges are willing to pay and the price at which sellers are willing to sell is the price of bitcoins.