# How to find values of Prev_Hash and Tx_Root

Tags: bitcoind, blockchain

https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/13347/27951

Based upon the answer here, it seems there's values per block with each `Prev_Hash` and also `Tx_Root`

There doesn't seem to be much documentation for how to access these. How can I find the `Prev_Hash` and the `Tx_Root` of the most recent block for example?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to access the values from code? Or just see them? You can see the values on a block explorer, but to decode the values from a raw block you'd need to understand the message [protocol format](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_documentation).

Comment: I'd like to see them for now but additionally access them by code eventually. I've found the `getblock` method which can be used to display the merkle tree, but how do I find the `blockHash` parameter to pass to that method, for say the last block or last 10 blocks? Not sure where I can find those `blockHash`es

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [a block on a block explorer](https://blockchain.info/block/000000000000000004f0cc322f551e39676f781186441614da3281bbc7d373e0).

[image]

Here the Prev_Hash is called 'Previous Block' and the Tx_Root is called 'Merkle Root'.

For more technical info, take a look at the [Protocol Documentation](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_documentation).

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Can I use `getblock` to access this via the Blockchain API? And also how can I find the hash of the latest block? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not an expert on Blockchain's API, but their documentation is here: https://blockchain.info/api/blockchain_api. For the latest block, it looks like you can use: https://blockchain.info/latestblock.

Comment: Whoops, I meant to say use `getblock` to access this via the Bitcoin API, typo.

Comment: You mean the Bitcoin Core RPC command `getblock`? Yes, it reports those values.