# How to see previous transactions?

Tags: transactions

This question is linked to [this one](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/46299/since-the-blockchain-is-public-how-can-we-see-it). I try to understand the bitcoin block by exploring and **viewing** every piece of information, since the blockchain is **public and shared**.

When the sender transacts some bitcoins to the recipient, he technically transact previous transactions. So in a transaction, it is possible to find successively all previous transactions. Where can we find this piece of information? (I remembered that I already saw this information on a website, I thought that was https://blockchain.info.)

Answer (score 1):

You are correct all transactions other than coinbase transactions utilize previous transaction outputs. You can navigate those using any number of block explorers:

- http://blockchain.info
- http://blockcypher.com
- http://blockr.io

And many more.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I would like to if it is possible to see more details. For example, in one transaction, we can see the sender's address and the recipient's. Then, if we want to see the previous transactions, we have to click on the sender's address, and then I have a list of transactions. This way, we can know that all transactions result on the final balance. But it is possible to clearly see what is exactly the previous transaction that is used? Since the amount won't be the same, it will be, 50% of transaction 1 (10 bitcoins received) to send 5 bitcoin.

Answer (score -1):

Try bitcoin visualization tool like https://www.blockseer.com

Comment: It appears that one cannot use blockseer without creating an account. This answer is not very helpful.