# What are the parts of a Blockchain?

Tags: blockchain

In the following article [What Are Bitcoins? How Do Bitcoins Work?](https://www.lifewire.com/what-are-bitcoins-2483146), it is mentioned that a blockchain is composed of three parts:

- Identifying address
- History
- Private key header

Although, after taking a look at this question "[Can someone explain how the Bitcoin Blockchain works?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/12427/can-someone-explain-how-the-bitcoin-blockchain-works)"
  it doesn't reflect what that article mentions.

If those three parts are the actual parts of a blockchain, can someone provide a better explanation for each one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not. They might be provided to try to provide a better explanation, but I don't even think that this purpose is achieved. There are several sentences throughout the article that make no sense at all, like:

> A bitcoin, at its core, is a very simple data ledger file called a 'blockchain'. A blockchain's file size is quite small, similar to the size of a long text message on your smartphone.

I would recommend you to look at the [question you mentioned](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/12427/can-someone-explain-how-the-bitcoin-blockchain-works/42515#42515) , that actually have two really good answers, and ignore the first article.

Comment: Agreed, the terminology in that article is totally confused, and the information about mining is hilariously obsolete.  Throw it away and read something else.