# Blockchain complete architecture

Tags: blockchain

Can someone give me brief description/reference about bitcoin blockchain architecture (preferably with a architecture diagram)?

Comment: Can you explain in a bit more detail what you're looking for, or perhaps what your end goal is? Without that I expect this question will get closed.

Comment: Here, I want to get idea about bitcoin blockchain architecture. i.e how blocks and transactions are arranged in chain?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can someone explain how the Bitcoin Blockchain works?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/12427/can-someone-explain-how-the-bitcoin-blockchain-works)

Comment: As the answer said check youtube and also other posts on this site. This is how I started. The question can be preformulated as what are the recommended learning resources for total bitcoin beginner? It's opinion based but I think would be valuable to have an answer for that.

Answer (score 2):

The question is too generic, probably this is why you have the downvotes. You don‘t show us your effort so far, what you have read, or how you did  your research. 
My generic response would be to start reading bitcoin.org, cause I assume you ask for bitcoins architecture in the bitcoin forum. There are many graphics, and proper explanations. Then you might look as well at Andreas Antonopolous book “Mastering Bitcoin”, which is also available online. And then there are some videos on YouTube...
My preferred high level view of the block chain is, that you have linked glass boxes (the public ledger with it blocks), with signed checks inside, having values transferred between two people.