# How to find out the latest valid UTXO one sat belongs to?

Tags: ordinals

Given a sat, e.g. 85941277214958.
How do I know which UTXO it belongs to?

Furthermore, is there a easy way to find out, if this sat belongs to another Ordinal?
I mean, I know there is no inscription on this sat now, but does this sat belong to another ordinal’s "fee section"?

Comment: This may be relevant https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/110435/how-are-satoshis-accounted-for but I am not sure because ordinals is a new application that is implemented separately from Bitcoin core. It is not obvious how they treat satoshis to me as the model for inscription ownership has been broken before: https://github.com/casey/ord/issues/2062#issuecomment-1555375928

I have also never read that satoshis were individually accounted for apart from their relevant UTXOs in Bitcoin core. Maybe theres docs on that?